# Prevent page jerk up on checking input

Tags: javascript, css

"Stars rating" works as intended https://codepen.io/462960/pen/WZXEWd but page jerks up after each click.
I tried to stop it

```
const labels = document.querySelectorAll('label');
function noDefault(e){
  e.preventDefault();
  };

labels.forEach(x => x.addEventListener('click', noDefault));
```

But it's not a desirable solution, because it stops inputs from being checked. I could not be used in web page. Any suggestion appreciated.

Comment: I see no jumping of the page in chrome.

Comment: @ВладимирМаксименко check my solution

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Solution: hide your label's input**

```
   &:not(:checked) {
      > input {
        display: none;
        //position: absolute;
        //top: -9999px;
        clip: rect(0,0,0,0);
      }
```